# How to turn off Microsoft Azure Visual Studio C# WebRole WorkerRole Debugging Output Noise?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

I'm just getting started with C#, and I'm playing around with WebRoles and WorkerRoles with Microsoft Azure. The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to use the debugger to see messages that I'm outputting to the console with `Debug.WriteLine`, but unfortunately, I have a hard time finding my output through all the noise generated by the WebRoles and WorkerRoles seemingly naturally.

The output window in Visual Studio doesn't appear to have any RegEx or phrase filtering like a lot of other debuggers do, so I can't simply focus on the output that I want to see... The output window is being spammed with messages like

```
WaWorkerHost.exe Information: 0 : Working
```

At a rate of about 5 per second.

My question is, how can i go about turning these (quite frankly) annoying messages off, or at the very least filter them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is *most likely* due to the code that is being generated for you when creating a worker or web role.
In WorkerRole.cs (or WebRole.cs), you have code that is similar to the following code:

```
    private async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // TODO: Replace the following with your own logic.
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("Working");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
```

Remove the line `Trace.TraceInformation`.

There are also these log outputs that gets spit out by the ServiceRuntime:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 500 : Role instance status check starting
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 502 : Role instance status check succeeded: Ready
```

Those can be turned off by setting the tracing level to Information or higher in WorkerRole.cs (or WebRole.cs), like this:

```
RoleEnvironment.TraceSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.Information;
```

This can be put in either `Run()` or `OnStart()`

---

**Extra / Off topic**

To disable other things, like Module load information etc, you can right click the *Output window* and deselect 'Module Load Messages', or other messages that is not of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. The fact that it just says "Working" was throwing me off...

Meanwhile, I also found out that if you click on the output window, it will stop bringing you down to the most recently output output. Additionally, if you press ctrl+f while your focus is in the output window, a box will appear that allows you to search for things in the output based on a RegEx or normal string which was perfect for me!